# Python: Replace values from one nested dictionary to another dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have two dictionaries CAN0 and CAN1 as follows:

```
CAN0 = {
    "signal11" : 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    "signal12" : 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    "signal21" : 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    "signal22" : 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    "signal31" : 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    "signal32" : 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
}

CAN1 = {
  "message1" : {
    "signal11" : 32,41,53,62,77
    "signal12" : 54,67,24,33,78
  },
  "message2" : {
    "signal21" : 55,53,63,62,77
    "signal22" : 34,65,94,97,24
  },
  "message3" : {
    "signal31" : 13,14,53,42,63
    "signal32" : 34,56,26,97,84
  },
}
```

I want to copy values from CAN1 and replace values in CAN0 to get updated CAN0 dictionary as follows:

```
CAN0 = {
    "signal11" : 0,0,0,32,41,53,62,77,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    "signal12" : 0,0,0,54,67,24,33,78,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    "signal21" : 0,0,0,55,53,63,62,77,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    "signal22" : 0,0,0,34,65,94,97,24,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    "signal31" : 0,0,0,13,14,53,42,63,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    "signal32" : 0,0,0,34,56,26,97,84,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
}
```

I am trying as following but keep getting " *'int' object is not subscriptable*" error.

```
for message in CAN1:
    for signal in CAN1[message]
        for i in range (3,7)    
            CAN0[str(signal)][i] = CAN1[message][signal][i]
```

In reality my dictionary has around 20-30 "messages" and each message has around 5-10 "signals". That is why I want to use for loop.

Comment: `can1 = {i: j for a in CAN1 for a, b in CAN1[a]}` , and use these signal value to update the can0 at location you desire

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
CAN0 = {
    "signal11": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    "signal12": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    "signal21": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    "signal22": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    "signal31": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    "signal32": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
}

CAN1 = {
    "message1": {"signal11": [32, 41, 53, 62, 77], "signal12": [54, 67, 24, 33, 78]},
    "message2": {"signal21": [55, 53, 63, 62, 77], "signal22": [34, 65, 94, 97, 24]},
    "message3": {"signal31": [13, 14, 53, 42, 63], "signal32": [34, 56, 26, 97, 84]},
}

for k, v in CAN1.items():
    for kk, vv in v.items():
        CAN0[kk][3:7] = vv

print(CAN0)
```

Prints:

```
{
    "signal11": [0, 0, 0, 32, 41, 53, 62, 77, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    "signal12": [0, 0, 0, 54, 67, 24, 33, 78, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    "signal21": [0, 0, 0, 55, 53, 63, 62, 77, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    "signal22": [0, 0, 0, 34, 65, 94, 97, 24, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    "signal31": [0, 0, 0, 13, 14, 53, 42, 63, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    "signal32": [0, 0, 0, 34, 56, 26, 97, 84, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With that structure, you can go directly to the values of the top level dictionary to get to the sub-dictionaris' items.  Then assign a subscript of the matching list:

```
for sigs in CAN1.values():
    for k,v in sigs.items():
        CAN0[k][3:8] = v

print(CAN0)
{'signal11': [0, 0, 0, 32, 41, 53, 62, 77, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 'signal12': [0, 0, 0, 54, 67, 24, 33, 78, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 'signal21': [0, 0, 0, 55, 53, 63, 62, 77, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 'signal22': [0, 0, 0, 34, 65, 94, 97, 24, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 'signal31': [0, 0, 0, 13, 14, 53, 42, 63, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 'signal32': [0, 0, 0, 34, 56, 26, 97, 84, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}
```